# How to fix a java.io.NotSerializableException when trying to save and load a text based ui game?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java and I am trying to implement two methods into my text based UI game save and load but I'm running into a few difficulties when I run the save command into the terminal I get a java.io.NotSerializableException I also get the same error for load. Essentially I just want to save the game state and load the game state, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or if I'm doing correctly, would really appreciate the help.

```
  public TikTakToeUI() {
    scnr   = new Scanner(System.in);
    game   = new TikTakToe();
    player = new Player();
  }

  private void execute(String command) 
  {
    File inFile = new File ("input.txt");
    
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Save")) {
      save(inFile);
    }else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Load")){
        load(inFile);
    }else {
      System.out.println("Unknown command (" + command + ")");
      displayMenu();
    }
  }

  private void save(File file)
  {
    try {   
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);   
        ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);   

        objectStream.writeObject(game);   
        objectStream.writeObject(scnr);   
        objectStream.writeObject(player);   
       
        objectStream.close();   
        fileStream.close();   

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "Save game state successfully.", 
            "Tik Tak Toe Game",   
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);   
    } catch (Exception e) {   
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            e.toString() + "\nFail to save game state.",   
            "Tik Tak Toe Game", 
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);   
    }   
  }

  private void load(File file)
  {
    try 
    { 
      FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);   
      ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileStream); 
    
  
      scnr = (Scanner) objectStream.readObject();
      game = (TikTakToe) objectStream.readObject();   
      player = (Player) objectStream.readObject();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {   
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            e.toString() + "\nFail to load game state.",   
            "Tik Tak Toe Game", 
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);   
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Does it make sense to you to save the scanner? A scanner is an object that is used to parse the textual input stream of the application. How does it represent "state"? My advice: do not use an object input/output stream. Instead, think of a textual format that represents the information you need to recreate the objects, and save/restore from a text file, only that information.

Comment: You are right I removed scanner since a new one can be created, what other alternatives can you suggest and how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save only `TikTakToe` and `Player` and `Scanner` create a new one when you starting the game.

What you should to update the `TikTakToe` and `Player` classes and implement the `Serializable` interface

```
public class TikTakToe implements Serializable {}
public class Player implements Serializable {}
```

Comment: I have just aded those changes and seem to get this java.io.NotSerializableException: Cell failed to save game state

Comment: Did you remove `Scanner` when WriteObject and ReadObject?

Comment: Yes I removed it from both methods save and load.

Comment: Hmmm, Strange behavior!

Comment: There is class called cell but I can't add `implements Serializable` since it is using `extends Observable` do you think this could be the issue?

Comment: You can use one extend and multiples implements of interfaces

Comment: Thanks this is working now added `implements Serializable ` to the Cell class, thank you very much.